# If I am in a comment (including empty lines), how do I get to the beginning of the comment?

Tags: comment, motion

I have the following problem:

I am in a comment or the empty lines after or within the comment. I want to get to the first line of the comment.

So no matter where I am in this commented block, I want to get to the beginning of line `;; blah blah`.

```
M-x butterfly

;; blah blah 

;; spoon

;; blah blah blah


;; swordfish
```

I think I have solved it, albeit clumsily:

```
(defun beginning-of-comment ()
      (interactive)
      (while
          (progn
            (beginning-of-line)
            (looking-at (rx-to-string (or
              `(: line-start (zero-or-more whitespace) (one-or-more ,comment-start))
              `(: line-start (zero-or-more whitespace) line-end))))))
      (previous-line))
```

Problem is, I cannot use the solution above, because it makes my emacs crash (and would presumably make other's emacs' with the same OS/emacs version crash too if I were to PR it).

There must be a more idiomatic, less verbose way to get to the beginning of a comment from within it.

Ninja edit: I thought of one more, but this also crashes emacs (becomes totally unresponsive):

```
(defun testing ()
  (interactive)
  (while (comment-forward) (progn (previous-line) (previous-line)))
```

Ps. I want this to work in as many modes as possible, so please use `comment-start`, do not hardcode the comment variable.

Comment: Comments typically have face associated with them. It would be easier to use text face to identify the beginning of comment (it will be also faster, since `looking-at` can be very slow, especially if there are lookaheads.

Comment: In your first version, the point is not moved inside the loop.

Comment: @wvxvw Thanks for the info, bit it does not sound like the most robust way. If you could an answer I'll UV it though. Thanks to you too JeanPierre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `syntax-ppss` to find out if the point is in a comment or not. When it is, it also provides information about where the comment started. The following code wraps this into a loop, skipping empty lines etc.

```
(defun my-comment-start-position ()
  "The position of the start of the current comment, or nil."
  (save-excursion
    (let ((res nil))
      (while (progn
               (skip-chars-backward " \t\n")
               (let ((state (syntax-ppss)))
                 (if (nth 4 state)
                     (let ((start (nth 8 state)))
                       (setq res start)
                       (goto-char start)
                       t)
                   nil))))
      res)))
```

The code is more robust than looking at regexp:s, since it handles difficult languages where the comment syntax must be defined programatically using a `syntax-propertize-function`.

Also, it is more robust than checking the `face` property:

- Some users don't like syntax highlighting and disable font-lock
- font-lock isn't active in batch mode
- font-lock only highlights visible parts of the buffer
- The `face` property doesn't have to contain a single symbol (see below), code reading it must handle all cases. (This happens, for example, when highlighing additional things inside comments.)
- Badly written font-lock keywords sometimes *replace* the existing face rather than prepending or appending
- Some comments may be highlighted using another face, e.g. if you have javadoc-style comments `font-lock-doc-face` is used.

From the elisp manual:

> ```
> ‘face’
>
> The ‘face’ property controls the appearance of the character (*note
> Faces::).  The value of the property can be the following:
>
>    • A face name (a symbol or string).
>
>    • An anonymous face: a property list of the form ‘(KEYWORD VALUE
>      …)’, where each KEYWORD is a face attribute name and VALUE is
>      a value for that attribute.
>
>    • A list of faces.  Each list element should be either a face
>      name or an anonymous face.  This specifies a face which is an
>      aggregate of the attributes of each of the listed faces.
>      Faces occurring earlier in the list have higher priority.
>
>    • A cons cell of the form ‘(foreground-color . COLOR-NAME)’ or
>      ‘(background-color . COLOR-NAME)’.  This specifies the
>      foreground or background color, similar to ‘(:foreground
>      COLOR-NAME)’ or ‘(:background COLOR-NAME)’.  This form is
>      supported for backward compatibility only, and should be
>      avoided.
> ```

Comment: This might just be me, but I think the part about how using face/font-locking is bad doesn't belong here but should be a comment to the "Use the face" answer (but you did that already) or even an answer to a new question on the site (so that you can give details, like you did here).

Comment: @YoungFrog, yes, I see your point. However, in this case, the use of checking the `face` property in cases like this is widespread (even I used to it until quite recently) so I decided to take the opportunity to explain why it's not a good idea.

Comment: If you are interested in a slightly shorter version of your function, I've added one to my post. Feel free to copy / edit my post. PS. There are also advantages of relying on face's value. The mode can use the comment face for whatever reason it likes, not necessary related to the parsing. From the user's standpoint, whenever something looks like a comment it is a comment, so it makes sense to take that into account. In any case, in practice, I didn't encounter the corner cases you mention (though they are valid).

Comment: Just to give you an example when `(syntax-ppss)` will do the wrong thing: `org-mode` comments aren't comments from its perspective, but you would still want to navigate them presumably.

Comment: @wvxvw, unfortunately, it overshoots the goal. When the first comment line is preceded with empty lines, your function returns the position of the first empty line rather than the first comment (which is the reason behind my `res` variable). Also, your code will not work when the point is in a string, as element 8 if the state is also used to point to the beginning of a string -- hence, you need to check element 4.

Comment: Well, if you want to skip both comments and whitespace, then, I imagine, you would also want to skip the whitespace before the comment, why not? I'll add the check for the fourth element.

Comment: @wvxvw, Not if the purpose of the function is to find the start of the comment. Besides, that is what the OP asked for, anyway.

Comment: Well, in such case your function returns a completely wrong value when called in something that is not a comment... (nil), while one would expect there to be a number. Or, it will also skip whitespace and linebreaks, even if there were no comments...

Comment: I designed it to return nil when the point wasn't in a comment. The user can use it like `(let ((pos (my-comment-start-position))) (if pos (...do something...) (...do something else...)))`. It will not "skip" anything, as the body is wrapped in a `save-excursion` to ensure that the point doesn't move.

Comment: @wvxvw. The OP asked for the code to go to the beginning of the comment when the point was in OR AFTER a comment, your code doesn't handle the latter. Finally, a friendly advice: 25+ years of writing elisp has taught me not to smart code things. It takes much longer to read 5 compact lines than 10 normal lines, it hides bugs, and it hinders further development of the code.

Comment: Wrt' skipping: yes, my bad. Still it won't work in Org at all. Well, 25 or 250 years... when I see the code that does `(if something t)`, I instantly don't trust the author to write good code. So, I won't read the 10 lines, instead, I'll rewrite whatever the author intended to do.

Comment: I typically use `(if cond (progn body t) nil)` when I both need conditionally evaluate some code and return the condition (in this case, it is used to control the loop). I could have used `(let ((c cond)) (when c body) c)` or `(and cond (progn body t))` but neither is better (considerably shorter or easier to read). I would never write `(when cond body)` since it evaluates to the value of `body` (when `cond` is true). Org-mode doesn't define comment characters in its syntax table, so effectively, it doesn't have comments.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example I could think of, not sure it will handle all corner cases (maybe some modes use different faces for eg.)

```lisp
(defun my/move-beginning-of-comment ()
  (interactive)
  (while (member (get-char-property (point) 'face)
                 (list font-lock-comment-face
                       font-lock-comment-delimiter-face))
    (backward-char)
    (skip-chars-backward " \t\n")))
```

Below is a slightly shorter way to write the same function Lindydancer posted:

```lisp
(defun my-comment-start-position ()
  "The position of the start of the current comment, or nil."
  (save-excursion
    (let (pos)
      (while (let* ((parse (syntax-ppss))
                    (move (and (nth 4 parse) (nth 8 parse))))
               (when move (goto-char (setq pos move))))
        (skip-chars-backward " \t\n"))
    (or pos (point)))))
```

Comment: Thanks. If others say this is a good way to do it, I might accept.

Comment: Take a look at `syntax-ppss` instead, it can tell you if you're in a comment or not, and where the comment started. Looking at the font-lock face is too fragile. To start, the `face` property can either be a symbol or a list of symbols, or even include a face plist. Another problem is that some font-lock rules replace the existing face, when that happens your code will not work.

Comment: Indeed too fragile. And some (parts of) the buffer could lack font-locking.

Answer (score -1):

More robust, but also more verbose:

```
(defun beginning-of-comment ()
  "When within a comment block - including empty lines - iterates backwards until the beginning."
  (interactive)
  (progn
    (while
        (progn
          (beginning-of-line)
          (or
           ;; Not working to use ?\n in rx-to-string for some reason
           (looking-at (rx (zero-or-more whitespace) ?\n))
           (looking-at (rx-to-string
                        `(: line-start (zero-or-more whitespace) (one-or-more ,comment-start))))))
      (previous-line))
    ;; If we end up in a code line, move one line forward.
    (unless
        (looking-at (rx (zero-or-more whitespace) line-end))
      (next-line)
      (beginning-of-line))))
```

Comment: Some modes have complicated commenting rules that comment-start  does not cover (they use syntax properties), so this is not generic enough.

Comment: `next-line` is for interactive use. You can use just  `forward-line` to replace both `next-line` and `beginning-of-line`.

Comment: Thanks. Should I delete this since the answer is suboptimal?

Comment: I don't think so. The voting system makes it easy enough to not even notice this answer for everyone not interested, and still possible to read it for the few interested people.